# pip installs 2.7 packages into /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages

Tags: python, pip

folks.

I'm trying to install packages like `tornado` using `pip` (simple pip, not `pip3.2`), but in installs it into  `/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages`, so `python2.7` can't find them.

What am I doing wrong? Should I set PYTHONPATH or whatever? (It seems quite dangerous).

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pip --version
pip 1.4.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-1.4.1-py3.2.egg (python 3.2)\
```

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**Answer:** `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.2`

Comment: Suspect you have pip for python 3 installed. Show us the output of `pip --version`. On my machine it inclues the path to the site-packages directory.

Comment: Run `which pip` and then `ls -la <pip-path>`, it might just be a symlink to pip3.2

Comment: @phasetwenty , yes it's `pip 1.4.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-1.4.1-py3.2.egg (python 3.2)` but no idea why it is so, I'm pretty sure I installed it from `apt` repos.

Comment: @PeterGibson , IFAI inderstand `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 282 Nov.  5 14:10 /usr/local/bin/pip` it is not a symlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$PATH: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

pip3.2 was in `/usr/local/bin` under name `pip` and pip2.7 was in `/usr/bin` under same name, so `$ pip` called 3.2 version.

I just had to `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.2` and restart my bash to rehash PATH.

I have no idea why it happened like this :)

Answer (score 2):

do you have python2 installed?

Don't know on which distribution you are, but sometimes there is pip2 as pip for python2 (example Arch Linux -> [link](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/python2-pip/)).

Otherwise check http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html for additional instructions

Comment: Yes, I have python2. And there's no pip2. I've tried installing it from scratch but it did nothing. I also purged python-pip but pip remained and it was pip3.2 . But there was one at `/usr/bin/pip` .